# IllegalArgumentException when querying field from HibernateCompositeUserType

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, composite-primary-key

We are using Spring Data JPA (v2.0.8.RELEASE) with Hibernate (v5.2.x) as the implementation. We noticed that Spring Data JPA has an issue when trying to query a field on a object that is mapped as a `CompositeUserType`.

Imagine the following class:

```
public class Currency {
    private String code;
    private int decimalPlaces;
    // getters and setters
}
```

The following example makes use of this class as a `CompositeType`

```
public class A {

    @Type(type = "CurrencyUserType")
    @Columns(
            columns = {
                    @Column(name = "CODE",
                    @Column(name = "DECIMAL_PLACES"
            }
    )
    private CurrencyUnit currency;
    // getters and setters and constructor
}
```

The Spring Data repository looks like this:

```
public class ARepository extends CrudRepository<A, Long> {

    Collection<A> findByCurrencyCode(String code);

}
```

However, when I try to execute the `findByCurrencyCode` query, the following exception is thrown:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.Collection ARepository.findByCurrencyCode(java.lang.String)! Illegal attempt to dereference path source [null.currency] of basic type
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:82)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:103)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:208)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:79)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lookupQuery(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:553)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$mapMethodsToQuery$1(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:546)
```

Hibernate seems to expect that we query the `A` class with a `Currency` object instead. But that implicies that we always have to specify all the fields in this object.

As an alternative, we we can make an `@Embeddable` from the Currency class as this works fine. Unfortunately we don't want to do this as this ties the Currency class to JPA annotations. We want to avoid this because we want to reuse the class in modules that are not aware of JPA (we are implementing our application in a Clean Architecture style).